# How to get three consecutive backslashes in Regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to create a regular expression such as:

```
/\\\s*\\\s*$/
```

I am trying it in this way:

```
Regexp.new('\\\s*\\\s*$') # => /\\s*\\s*$/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just to be clear, you want a regex to match 2 \ chars at the end of a line with zero or more whitespaces after each \?

Comment: I think you should say you want the compliled regex to be `/\\\s*\\\s*$/`.  Having `s` is in your example (rather than 'a', say) has caused some confusion, as some have read it as `\s`.  Please don't change that, however, as it's instructive.

Comment: Question is not clear. The regex you show includes two occurrences of a single backslash followed by an arbitrary number of space character, which is different from what you have in the title.

Answer (score 4):

Well (`\\`) matches a *single* backslash. Backslash serves as an escape character for *Regexp*.

```
rgx = Regexp.new('\\\\\\s*\\\\\\s*$')
```

A more verbose way of doing this would be the following as [@Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) stated.

```
rgx = Regexp.new('\\{3}s*\\{3}s*$')
```

Comment: `Regexp.new('\\{3}s*\\{3}s*$')` is less prone to error and makes it clear that `s` is a literal rather than part of `\s`.

Answer (score 1):

Using literal notation avoids some confusion. This compiles to what you *said* you want:

```
/\\\s*\\\s*$/
```

Though, to be clear, this still matches a single backslash, optional whitespace a single backslash and more optional whitespace. Backslashes are escaped when you inspect a regexp.

Comment: π, I think the asker's question is embodied in the title and the  code he/she presents is a failed attempt to achieve that objective.